# Copying a function object from one window to another

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to copy a function (or any object for that matter) from one window context to another in Javascript?

Let's say I have a *parent* window with a *frame* in it. The *frame* defines a function `foo()`, which I'd like to copy to the outer window. (One reason to do it would be so that `foo()` is available when the *frame* document navigates to a different URL.)

I know I can easily create a **reference** to `foo()` in the *parent* by doing

```
function foo() { ... }    
parent.foo = foo;
```

But with this method `foo()` still lives in the *frame* document, and will not be available to the *parent* should *frame* get unloaded.

I know I can also create a new function in the *parent* by using the Function constructor:

```
parent.foo = new parent.Function(" ... ");
```

However, this requires me to have my function as a JS string.

DOM supports moving nodes from one document to another via `importNode()`. Does Javascript have a similar feature?

Comment: Would it not be better to just write the javascript function inside the parent? The frame will always have access to the parent. That way you can use the function in either the parent or the frame. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Theoretically this is possible, but there are some constraints in my case. In particular, my script will sometimes be included into the frame document, and I don't want to restrict people from doing so.

Comment: @levik: just have the function in the parent, and *pull* it into the frame (rather than push it to the parent). That way if the frame unloads, the parent's copy is still alive and well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nitko's solution seems to be correct, though a little more work is required. This function seems to work on FF2, FF3, IE7 and Chrome:

```
  function importFunction(fn, win) {
    var code = fn.toString();
    var params = code.match(/\(([^)]*)\)/);
    if (typeof(params[1]) !== 'undefined') {
      params = params[1].split(/\s*,\s*/);
    } else {
      params = null;
    }
    code = code.replace(/^[^{]*{/, '');
    code = code.replace(/}$/, '');
    if (params) {
      return new win.Function(params, code);
    } 
    return new win.Function(code);
  }
```

The returned function can be used in the needed window. Something like:

```
parent.foo = importFunction(foo, parent);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always get the code for a given function calling it's `toString()` method:

```
parent.foo = new parent.Function( originalFunction.toString() );
```

Though I don't certainly know it's available in every browser, I think I've seen it working in major browsers, modern versions.

Comment: the toString returns "function(){ ... }", so this won't